# What would be the best way to track downloads by user?

Tags: users, plugins

Is anybody familiar with a plugin (similar to EE's Link Vault) that tracks all downloads, by user?

Comment: Shanan, sorry for grave-digging but did you ever make a plugin for this? I'm exploring implementing similar functionality and am still a baby when it comes to plugin development. Any sort of ideas for a head-start would be really helpful.

Comment: Kirk, this was for a project that would have brought an EE install over to Craft. To date, they haven't pulled the trigger on making the switch, so we haven't had the occasion to create the plugin. That said, I'm also a baby when it comes to Craft plugins.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We all need to start somewhere. "I started out as a child..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can track the number of times a file has been downloaded using the [Asset Count](https://github.com/verbb/asset-count) plugin by Verbb.

As the readme shows, rather than linking directly to your files, you’d point the link to the plugin’s controller action:

```html
<a href="{{ actionUrl('asset-count/count', { id: file.id }) }}" target="_blank"></a>
```

Comment: Any news for this on Craft 3?

Comment: @mateostabio Now on Craft 3 - https://github.com/verbb/asset-count/releases/tag/1.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Until the plugin store is a real thing, the most comprehensive list of plugins available for Craft is currently here: http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins

The closet thing I'm seeing to what you're looking for is http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/counter

Comment: Thanks, Brad -- I was punting to see if someone was doing something off the grid. Time for a custom plugin.